# What is the single-word noun meaning "Someone who participates in a Winterfest"?

Tags: single-word-requests, winterfest

If someone who goes to the Theatre is a Theatregoer, what is the single-word noun for someone who participates in a Winterfest? I am assuming it would not be "Winterfester" as that sounds more like some kind of suppurating wound.

Comment: 'Is there word for it'? It's just not even a thing.

Comment: It would perhaps be a good starting point to consider the possible name for a person who takes place in any 'festival'. I can't think of an obvious one, but I am wondering if 'reveller' might get close? So Winter Reveller?

Comment: Winterfestering?

Comment: Having refused to clean the wound in November, by late December it began Winterfestering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Winterfest-goer***.

> "I have been coming down since I was little," said one WinterFest-goer.
>
> [[newsnet5.com]](http://www.newsnet5.com/news/local-news/cleveland-metro/winterfest-on-public-square-in-cleveland-draws-crowd-even-in-cold-saturday)

<sub>*Winterfester* sounds rather German.</sub>